# How do you only pass a model to the view once it has fetched all it's data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How do you only pass a model to the view once it has fetched all it's data? I have a model called Messages, which fetches an array with 100 message objects. I want to pass this to my view to render but when I pass them nothing happends because my model has not completted the act of getting all the messages yet. How do I do this?

**app.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  messages = new Messages();
  messagesView = new MessagesView({model: messages});
});
```

**messagesView.js**

```
var MessagesView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initiaize: function() {
    console.log('works');
  },

  sanitizeHtml: function(html) {
    if (html === null) {
      return 'null';
    } else if (html === undefined) {
      return 'undefined';
    }

    var result = "";
    for (var i = 0;i < html.length;i++) {
      switch (html[i]) {
      case ">":
        result += "&gt;";
        break;
      case "<":
        result += "&lt;";
        break;
      default:
        result += html[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    return result;
  },

  getUserName: function(){
      var name = 'username'.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
      var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
          results = regex.exec(location.search);
      return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  },

  renderFriends: function(){
    $('#friends-list').empty();
    _.each(this.friends, function(friend) {
      $('#friends-list').append('<li>' + friend + '</li>');
    });
  },

  renderMessages: function() {
    var context = this;
    $('#msg-log').text('');
    _.each(this.model.get('data').results, function(msg) {
      var text = context.sanitizeHtml(msg.text);
      var username = context.sanitizeHtml(msg.username);
      if (msg.room === context.model.roomName) {
        var url = $("<a class='link' href='' data-name='" + username + "'>" + username + "</a>");
        $('#msg-log').append(url);
        if (_.contains(context.model.friends, username)) {
          $('#msg-log').append($("<span><b>: " + text.substring(0, 44) + "</b></span>"));
        } else {
          $('#msg-log').append($("<span>: " + text.substring(0, 44) + "</span>"));
        }
        $('#msg-log').append('<br>');
      }
    });
  },
});
```

**messagesModel.js**

```
var Messages = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    setEventListeners();
    this.set('friends', []);
    this.set('data', []);
    this.set('roomName', undefined);
    this.fetch();
  },

  send: function(message){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chatterbox',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({
       text: message,
       username: this.getUserName(),
       room: this.get('roomName')
      }),
    });
  },

  fetch: function(){
    var context = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chatterbox',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        limit: 14,
        order: '-createdAt'
      },
      success: function(data) {context.set('data', data) }
    });
  },
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically speaking if you have 100 messages then fetching it through a model is completely incorrect.

A Backbone Model is an single entity which may be considered similar to a row in your database table.

For e.g. a message model should have the columns of your databse table as its properties and a an instance of your model maps exactly to one row in your table.

What you are actually trying to fetch using the ajax call above is number of messages, for which you should use a Backbone Collection. A backbone collection holds number of models in it.

So in your case, your backbone collection for message will contain the 100 messages you are trying to fetch.

Use the fetch method of collection to retrieve your messages from the backend.

For rendering your view after the data has been fetched you can define an event listener for the backbone collection's "reset" event.

Always remember, to fetch a list of rows from your table use collections.

A model is similar to an individual row in your database table.

Comment: I understand the notion of using a Backbone collection to represent multiple entities, but I do not know how to represent a model as only being a single message because the sever I am fetching data from returns 100 messages at a time. Am I suppose to fetch that, iterate through them and make each one a model, and then make that into a collection?

Comment: You will have to fetch your messages using the collection. Backbone collection has an url property which helps you define from where should the collection fetch data from. Define the url as in your ajax then call the fetch method. When the data is returned in an array of json format that would be attached to your collection. The collection would know what kind if data its fetching with the help of model attribute which in your case is a message.